# What's the point of having models in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So far I have yet to see the value of having models in WPF. All my ViewModels, by convention, have an associated Model. Each of these Models is a virtual clone of the their respective ViewModel. Both the ViewModel and Model classes implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the ViewModel just delegates everything to the Model anyway.

Why bother having Models then? Why can't I just move my Model logic up into the ViewModel and call it a day?

It seems rather redundant (that is, not **DRY**) to have MVVM, and just use VVM by default unless some special edge case demands a Model.

If using explicit model classes better supports unit testing, for example, or some other best practice, I can see the value.

Comment: My model is almost always a DAL, but that's just me.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET So your model is usually some static class with a bunch of helper methods?

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Comment: So your ViewModel just calls DAL.DoStuff() via ICommands?

Comment: I'm pretty lazy and rarely do the commands, but yes. I've also had a WCF proxy as my Model and I just called its functions directly (not the greatest MVVM practice, but saved a bunch of un-needed boiler plate code).

Comment: Don't add complexity if it does not provide a benefit. Depending on your project, it might be very well beneficial for readability and maintainability to treat some or all (data) model(s) and view model(s) as the same. Just sticking to a pattern because that is written in a book is what a novice should do so to learn that pattern. However, as soon as you gain experience you should also know how and where to bend the rules for the benefit of readibility/maintainability of your code.

Comment: @elgonzo This is my first WPF app. After 4 weeks, I'd say I have sufficient perspective to see that I'm writing pointlessly redundant code that offers no benefit. If it better supports unit testing, for example, or some other best practice, I can see the value.

Comment: 4 weeks isn't enough perspective Mark :) - but this is often contested you're right. IMO the main point of argue is about the PropertyChanged and redundancy on that side, at least that's me

Comment: Mark, if you speak generally about "view models" vs. "models", then the theory and the reasoning about them is out there in the wild internet. Regarding your project, as said don't bother too much about a separation between (data)model and viewmodel, if you don't find a benefit in doing so. In many projects you will see in the layout/structure of the folders and sources/classes that model and viewmodel overlap or meld completely. Such an approach is absolutely fine if you are not dealing with large-scale software (whatever that means) involving many people in different teams (but even then...)

Comment: @elgonzo I just discovered Fody, which definitely helped with the INPC mess. I am removing redundant models where I don't see a clear benefit. So far so good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think of it as an abstraction, let's say you need to build a screen to display a list of Employees and make a Selection, Search or Filter. Then we break it up in components. You will require:

1. An `Employee` class (Model)
2. An  `EmployeeManagementViewModel` to prepare and present your list of Employees and manage state changes for your View (e.g. can contain a `SelectedEmployee`, Filter Search text, etc) to be used by your `EmployeeManagementView`
3. A list of Employees (Which will live in your `EmployeeManagementViewModel`)

Most likely you will already have an `Employee` class. If that's the case then you just need to expose that model in your `EmployeeManagementViewModel` as an `ObservableCollection` of Employees.

In case you **don't** already have an Employee class you may decide to create an `EmployeeViewModel` and add your `Employee` properties there like `FirstName`, `LastName`, etc.

Technically this will work but conceptually it bothers me because an `EmployeeViewModel` **is not** an Employee (**it contains** an employee). If you're abstracting reality then, the blueprint of an Employee should not include properties or methods to be used by a View. To me Employee should be a POCO which could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and nothing more than that. You're separating View state from the Model itself. Having an Employee POCO makes it easier to UnitTest, create mock employees, map it to a database table through an ORM,  etc.

As the name implies the ViewModel is the model for your View and the Model is the model for your business domain

Anyway that's how I see it. When I started doing MVVM work I had that same question but over the years seems like it makes sense.

Comment: So I've been at this for a year now. I actually forgot that I posted this question. My application is structured just as you describe.

Comment: @MarkRichman I came here because I saw your recent FluentValidation question which I answered. I hope that solution works for you

Comment: oh yes thanks so much...trying it out in the morning!

Answer (score 5):

The model is just the low level application data.

The view model is more specific.

- It's like a window tapping into the data **tailored** for the view.
- It also **augments** the model with details needed for the view. A good example is pagination.
- A model can have **more than one** view model. These view models would offer different aspects of the data.
- You can create a **mashup** of different data sources. A view model cleanly façades the models involved.

That means there is no 1:1 relationship between models and view models.

So, if you just display the low level data without a lot of additional logic, features, summaries, aggregations, filters, etc. you can do away with view models and just use the model directly. This seems to be the case with your project.

Answer (score 4):

The model can be auto-generated (Entity Framework), or it might not be a specific class at all (think of a DataTable).

I assume that if you say "I don't use a model", you *do* in fact use a model, you just don't call it that way.

Comment: I am thinking more in terms of how I physically structure my solution. That is, folders like Views, ViewModels, Models, etc. I detest filling up a folder with classes just to satisfy some pattern.

Comment: @MarkRichman: ...and rightly so! Patterns are supposed to help you solve a specific problem (in that case: separation of concern), not to create annoying boilerplate code.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, even in MVVM you can expose your Model directly in the VM and bind through it to the Model. `{Binding MyModel.MyModelsProperty}` where `DataContext = ViewModel` that way you don't have to necessarily wrap everything unless that is just your style to do so.

The ViewModel and Model have different responsibilities. For example, consider designing a file explorer with a tree view of folders. Each node in the tree view is a Directory/Folder. The directories are the models and they have properties related to the file system. The ViewModel may wrap or expose these properties for the TreeView nodes to display (For example the Name of the directory), but it also adds additional information such as "IsEditing" and "IsExpanded" to determine the state that the node is in.

Comment: In your file explorer example, what would your model(s) be?

Comment: I edited it, the directories would be the models so perhaps a list of DirectoryInfo objects or something along those lines. But you still need to have other information for editing. When a user goes to rename you need a temporary name for example which can be rolled back if the ESC to cancel, etc.

Comment: Okay, so you wouldn't have a dedicated model class. Your VM would just have a `IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo>` member or similar.

Comment: binding to model via view-model is not the best, not to my liking at least - that kind of muds the whole thing. I know you save on PropertyChanged if ever needed, but preferable is to wrap even with redundancy. I admit, the whole design isn't perfect in that respect IMO.

Comment: Well technically, the DirectoryInfo class IS a model class, but you didn't write it yourself. In my applications I have a lot of domain specific data objects that need to be displayed, that I have in fact written myself. Generic examples might be Orders, Customers, Accounts, etc.  Your ViewModel might be a list of orders, a filter, currently selected order, sales person responsible, etc.. It aggregates multiple models and additional information that is collected to be displayed.

Answer (score 4):

You're just talking about one pattern in MVVM, actually there are more.

In [Stateful viewmodel](http://www.xamlpatterns.com/stateful-view-model) you don't actually delegate things to Models, Viewmodel itself maintains its state, so as you said in this pattern you can almost ignore the model as you can have state in VM itself.

> To create isolation between business logic and presentation, data
>   should be removed from the view. The stateful view model pattern moves
>   data into the view model using XAML data binding. This allows the view
>   model to be tested without constructing a view, and it allows the view
>   to change with minimal impact on the business logic.

In [Stateless viewmodel](http://www.xamlpatterns.com/stateless-view-models) you delegate the calls to Model, which is what you're probably referring to.

Note that you don't necessarily implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Model`. Just implementing it in VM is fine as long as you don't change the properties directly in Model.

So why do we need VM and Model? VM is for supporting view like providing Commands, etc and Model is just to hold the piece of data abstract the same.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience when you just use Domain models as the ViewModel (as a property of the VM) you end up with a lot of Keys that require you to either go get the text value and store somewhere else or you end up adding the property to the VM anyway.  Your view typically has more info than just one single domain model (e.g. related objects, display values, text status values etc..), something that the Domain model has no need for and would ultimately weigh it down.  The view model is dedicated to the needs of the view, it keeps coding the View simple and non-complex.

Answer (score 2):

In general, my Models end up being a Data Access Layer, be it through Entity Framework, a WCF proxy, or some other class.

Depending on concurrency issues, the class could be static or instanced. If you can separate the behavior enough, you could "split" the DAL classes into a separate model for each view model, but duplicate code could become a problem.

Comment: In my case, I have a class that wraps up a bunch of logic, including a WCF proxy, all in an assembly outside my WPF app. It seems silly, and perhaps wrong, to try to fold all that into distinct model classes to satisfy some pattern.

Comment: As other commenters have pointed out, following the pattern just to have boiler plate code is definitely not doing you any favors. For me, the "Model" is more of an idea than an actual set of classes, so the "Model" can be whatever your "ViewModel" talks to in order to get data.

Comment: Just call that "assembly outside my WPF app" your Model.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia: [MVVM](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)

> Model: as in the classic MVC pattern, the model refers to either (a) a domain model which represents the real state content (an object-oriented approach), or (b) the data access layer that represents that content (a data-centric approach).

Your `ViewModel` isn't a substitute for your domain `Model`. It acts as an intermidiate between your view and the model, including commands, binding collections to your view, validation, etc.

Your domain model should also be reusable across `ViewModels`. If you implement it all in the VM you will end up abusing the **DRY** principle by sharing specific  VM logic across multiple VMs.